# insert date into mongdb using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, python-3.5

I am reading the data from the excel sheet and need to dump the data to MongoDB. But the date column is inserting as a number, not the ISODate(''). My code is

```
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheetname=0,index_col=None,converters={'Date':     str})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],format ="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df)
records = json.loads(df.T.to_json()).values()
print(records)
db = client.local
print(db)
evbal = db.test.insert_many(records)
```

output :

```
{"Date":1519862400000,"AgentID": "xxxx", "LOB": "yy", "Channel":"os"}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are storing a timestamp instead of a datetime object, which can be serialized & stored in MongoDB. I don't have access to your Excel file, and so I can't really play around with it, but I would suggest trying something like

```
from datetime import datetime
....
df['Date'] = datetime.fromtimestamp(df['Date'])
```